# Python Set Button Text While busy

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and I am trying to create a program but I can't even get the basics right. I have a button app that looks like this:

```
#simple GUI
from tkinter import *
import time

#create the window
root = Tk()

#modify root window
root.title("Button Example")
root.geometry("200x50")

button1state = 0

def start():
    count = 0
    button1["text"] ="Busy!"
    while (count < 5):
        root.after(1000)
        count = count + 1

def button1clicked():
    global button1state
    if button1state == 0:
        start()
        button1["text"] ="On!"
        button1state = 1
    else:
        button1["text"] ="Off!"
        button1state = 0

app = Frame(root)
app.pack()

button1 = Button(app, text ="Off!", command = button1clicked)
button1.pack()

#kick off the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Now everything works except it doesn't change the button text to busy while 
`**start()**` is called. How can I fix this? Once I've got it working I want to use images to show the user that its OFF ON and BUSY. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You need to force the GUI to update before starting the task:

```
def start():
    count = 0
    button1.configure(text="Busy!")
    root.update()  # <-- update window
    while (count < 5):
        root.after(1000)
        count = count + 1
```

But if you don't want your GUI to be frozen while the task is executed, you will need to use a thread as Dedi suggested.

Comment: I agree but you might need one if you want to perform some more complex task.

Comment: the same way: `window_name.update()`, where `window_name` can be something like `self.window` or just `self` if your class is inheriting from a tkinter widget.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a dream now. Where do I post my script to get help on checking it for any uneeded code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a thread in order to make you function as a "background event" while your interface is working. Consider using that :

```
from threading import Thread
```

and then :

```
my_thread=Thread(target=start())
my_thread.start()
```

Where the first "start()" is the name of your function and the second one a call for the thread to begin.